# Python Pymc3 Out of Bounds Index

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I work in the insurance industry and would like to compare our standard GLM Poisson regression models to Bayesian models. However, I'm not sure how to incorporate both categorical AND continuous predictor variables inside the model. I've tried the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import seaborn as sns
from pymc3 import Model, Normal, HalfNormal, Poisson, find_MAP, NUTS, sample, summary, traceplot
import theano 

#create fake data
n = 1000
y = np.random.poisson(lam = 1, size = n)
lower = 5000
upper = 150000
mu, sigma = 60000, 30000
X = stats.truncnorm(
    (lower - mu) / sigma, (upper - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
value = X.rvs(1000)
married = ['m', 's', 's', 'm', 'm']
marital_status = married * 200
credit = ['GF', '375', '400', '425', '450', '475', '500', '525', '550', '575', '600', '625', '650',
         '675', '700', '725', '750', '775', '800', 'T', '575', '600', '625', '650',
         '675', '700', '725', '750', '775', '800', '750', '775', '800', '750', '775', '800'
          ,'775', '800', '775', '800', '700', '725', '750', '775', '800', 'T', '575', '600', '625',
          '650']
credit_group = credit * 20
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['claims'], data = y)
df['value'] = value
df['marital_status'] = marital_status
df['credit_group'] = credit_group

marital_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['marital_status'], drop_first=True)
credit_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df['credit_group'], drop_first=True)

df['single_status'] = marital_dummies
df = pd.concat([df, credit_dummies], axis = 1)
df.drop(['marital_status', 'credit_group'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
df.head()

value_shared = theano.shared(df['value'].values)
single_shared = theano.shared(df['single_status'].values)
x3_shared = theano.shared(df['400'].values)
x4_shared = theano.shared(df['425'].values)
x5_shared = theano.shared(df['450'].values)
x6_shared = theano.shared(df['475'].values)
x7_shared = theano.shared(df['500'].values)
x8_shared = theano.shared(df['525'].values)
x9_shared = theano.shared(df['550'].values)
x10_shared = theano.shared(df['575'].values)
x11_shared = theano.shared(df['600'].values)
x12_shared = theano.shared(df['625'].values)
x13_shared = theano.shared(df['650'].values)
x14_shared = theano.shared(df['675'].values)
x15_shared = theano.shared(df['700'].values)
x16_shared = theano.shared(df['725'].values)
x17_shared = theano.shared(df['750'].values)
x18_shared = theano.shared(df['775'].values)
x19_shared = theano.shared(df['800'].values)
x20_shared = theano.shared(df['GF'].values)
x21_shared = theano.shared(df['T'].values)

#
np.random.seed(123)

poisson_model = Model()

with poisson_model:

    #priors for unknown model paramters
    alpha = Normal('alpha', mu = 0, sd = 1)
    beta = Normal('beta', mu = 0, sd = 1, shape = 2)
    sigma = HalfNormal('sigma', sd = 1)
    x1 = single_shared
    x2 = value_shared
    x3 = x3_shared
    x4 = x4_shared
    x5 = x5_shared
    x6 = x6_shared
    x7 = x7_shared
    x8 = x8_shared
    x9 = x9_shared
    x10 = x10_shared
    x11 = x11_shared
    x12 = x12_shared
    x13 = x13_shared
    x14 = x14_shared
    x15 = x15_shared
    x16 = x16_shared
    x17 = x17_shared
    x18 = x18_shared
    x19 = x19_shared
    x20 = x20_shared
    x21 = x21_shared

    mu = alpha + beta[0]*alpha + beta[1]*x1 + beta[2]*x2 + beta[3]*x3 + beta[4]*x4 + beta[5]*x5 + beta[6]*x6+ beta[7]*x7+ beta[8]*x8+ beta[9]*x9+ beta[10]*x10+ beta[11]*x11+ beta[12]*x12 + beta[13]*x13+ beta[14]*x14+ beta[15]*x15+ beta[16]*x16+ beta[17]*x17+ beta[18]*x18+ beta[19]*x19+ beta[20]*x20+ beta[21]*x21

    claims = Poisson('claims', mu = mu, sigma = sigma, observed = df['claims'])

    start = find_MAP(fmin=optimize.fmin_powell)

    step = NUTS(scaling = start)

    trace = sample(1000, step, start = start)
```

I'm not sure why, but I keep getting a 'Index Error: index out of bounds' error.

Comment: Your `beta` is only `shape=2`, but shouldn't it be `shape=22` given how you're indexing it for the `mu` calculation?

Comment: thanks @merv.  Changing that did get rid of the index error.   Now I'm finding an error with my start variable which I will now research.  Thanks again.